# Module.autoload not working as expected - Ruby

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

I'm trying to practice using the autoload function in a Ruby module. I have two modules `A` and `B`. I want to load module `B` in `A`'s namespace but I'm getting an uninitialized constant error. Both files are in the same folder. Here is my code:

a.rb

```
module A

end
A.autoload(:B, "./b.rb")
A::B.test #this line causes the error.
```

b.rb

```
module B
    def self.test
        puts "test called"
    end
end
```

Error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
a.rb:7:in `<main>': uninitialized constant A::B (NameError)
Did you mean?  A::B
               B
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It's because you need to namespace the module B inside module A:

```
# b.rb
module A
  module B
    def self.test
      puts "test called"
    end
  end
end
```

With this code, `ruby a.rb` will work as expected.

Oddly, your currently code actually *does* load the B file, but only after raising an error for trying to access the nonexistent `A::B`. Let me explain:

1. You register the `A.autoload(:B, "./b.rb")`
2. You call `A::B` - this performs the autoload to obtain `B` (at the toplevel) but then *afterwards* tries to evaluate `A::B`, which fails because of the way you've defined `B`.

For example, see what happens if you keep `b.rb` as what you originally had, and change `a.rb` to the following (which I don't recommend, I'm just explaining the behavior):

```
module A
end

A.autoload(:B, "./b.rb")

begin
  A::B.test # This errors, but still performs the autoload
rescue NameError
end

B.test # this works because of the autoload
```